# Referencing the same information twice on a report with different criteria

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a report designed to show what stock needs to be converted.

On the report I have a source product code and a result product code (source product is converted into 1 or more result products)

I also want to have a description for both products, this is where I had my problem.

(The product codes and descriptions are all stored in a table named products/stock)

I managed to put the description for the source product on just fine, dragging the information onto the report and selecting how the two tables are linked.

However, now when I drag another description box onto the report, it assumes that I want the same relationship as before and just displays the same description from products/stock.

This isn't what I want because I want it to now display the description for the new product to be made!

I have tried using this code, linked with a textbox on the report, but it tells me that the value is Null?

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim strResultDesc As String

strResultDesc = DLookup("[Description]", "[products/stock]", "[Product Code] = '" & Me.txtResultPC & "'")

Me.Text57.Value = strResultDesc

End Sub
```

[image: Screenshot of Form]

The random rectangle above is the textbox that should contain the description.

[image: Screenshot in design view]

This is a screenshot of how the report is made up.

[image: The field list (as requested)]

Screenshot of field list as requested.

The record source of the report:

```
SELECT [Stock Conversion Items].SCID AS [Stock Conversion Items_SCID],
  [Stock Conversion Items].[Result PC],
  [Stock Conversion Items].Quantity,
  [Stock Conversion].[Source PC],
  [Stock Conversion].Status,
  [Stock Conversion].SCID AS [Stock Conversion_SCID],
  [products/stock].Description,
  [Stock Conversion].[Created By],
  [Stock Conversion].Quantity AS [Quantity_Stock Conversion]
FROM [products/stock] INNER JOIN ([Stock Conversion] 
  INNER JOIN [Stock Conversion Items]
    ON [Stock Conversion].[SCID] = [Stock Conversion Items].[SCID]) 
    ON [products/stock].[Product Code] = [Stock Conversion].[Source PC]
  WHERE ((([Stock Conversion].Status)="NEW"));
```

Comment: It appears you are using a subreport for the result product details. If this is the case, then bear in mind that the main report and the subreport have independent fields. Click first on a control within the subreport (so the field list displays the fields from the subreport), then drag the description from the field list to the subreport.

Comment: This code doesn't work because it's only executed each time the subreport opens (in this case, once for each record on the main report). You would have to use the Current event, which runs once for each record.

Comment: And you think that would work?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's needlessly complex, if the suggestion I proposed in the first comment works.

Comment: (After seeing the screenshot) OK, no subreport. In that case, the field list (from where you're dragging the description) needs to have two descriptions - one for the source product, and one for the result product. Can you post a screenshot of the field list?

Comment: Also, it would help to see the record source of the report.

Comment: The recordsource doesn't include the FROM clause. The column `[products/stock].Description` could come from a table joined to the source product code, or joined to the result product code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add another "copy" of the `products/stock` table to the query, joined to the result product.

In the query designer, if you right-click on the background of the upper pane and select **Show Table..**, you can choose the same table multiple times. Add the `products/stock` table again; it will get a name like `products/stock_1`. Then, create a join from the `Stock Conversion Items` table to the new table, from the `Result PC` field to the `SCID` field.

Drag the `Description` field from `products/stock_1` to the lower pane, and close the query designer.

Now the field list will show two Description fields: `products/stock.Description` and `products/stock_1.Description`. The second field contains the result product description.

Comment: Brilliant, been stuck on this for days! So I thought i'd give an all out description of my problem and you nailed it. Cheers!